# Clear CSS binding

Tags: knockout.js

I have a computed css binding like this

```
this.iconCss = ko.computed(function () {
    var css = { icon: true };
    css[this.state().toLowerCase()] = true;
    return css;
}, this);
```

What it does is displaying a icon visualizing the state of each step in a workflow, for example i want the css to look like this `class="icon running`" or `class="icon failed"` etc

The problem is that the css binding wont clear the old classes so if i first have this `class="icon queued"` and change state to running the new class will be `class="icon queued running"` which is wrong, it doesn't matter that I assign it a new object literal the old classes will not be cleared, one way is to store the object literal and iterate over it and set all its properties to false. That's my last resort if there isn't a cleaner built in way of clearing the css binding.

**edit:** This is a solution but I don't like it

```
this.iconCssState = {};

this.iconCss = ko.computed(function () {
    for (var index in this.iconCssState) {
        this.iconCssState[index] = false;
    }

    this.iconCssState.icon = true;
    this.iconCssState[this.state().toLowerCase()] = true;
    return this.iconCssState;
}, this);
```

Comment: Did you try to use the 'attr' with 'class' binding instead ? like **attr: { 'class': somevalue }**. This should normally replace the whole class value each time. In that case the computed value should return something like 'icon queued'.

Comment: A problem with that one is that IE has problems with the class attribute, you have to use the className attribute

Comment: Make sure you put _class_ between quotes. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nC7XY/2/) which works on IE8 for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want using my [`class`](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/wiki/Bindings---class) binding. (Note that in the next version of Knockout, 2.2, you'll be able to use the `css` binding in the same way.)

```
<div class="icon" data-bind="class: state().toLowerCase()"></div>
```